# Is there a phrase to refer to the moment of the full moon?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, colloquialisms, science

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_moon#Characteristics):

> A full moon is often thought of as an event of a full night's duration. This is somewhat misleading because its phase seen from Earth continuously waxes or wanes (though much too slowly to notice in real time with the naked eye). Its maximum illumination occurs at the moment waxing has stopped. Many almanacs list full moons not only by date, but also by their **exact time** ...

Colloquially, I've always heard of a full moon as a night's event. Is there a word or a phrase that specifically refers to the exact moment at which the moon is brightest, one that wouldn't be confused with "full moon"?

Comment: 'Exact time' is only well-defined theoretically; actual time can never be measured / given precisely. You perhaps mean 'rounded to the nearest second'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'll accept that. I'm looking for something that is more precise than a full night.

Comment: My grasp of the spatial geometry may be a bit suspect, but it seems to me the only time when the Moon could *in principle* be 100% "full" is when it's *exactly* in line with the Earth and the Sun. But that would be a total lunar eclipse, so you wouldn't be able to see it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cite from [Freedom Vidya](http://shrifreedom.org/vedic-astrology/amavasya-the-dark-moon/) is just too precisely relevant to pass up...

> *The exact moment of **syzygy** was unknown until scientific advancements to calculate the lunar cycle became more accurate.*

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online...](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/syzygy)

> **syzygy** (Noun, Astronomy)
>    A conjunction or opposition, especially of the moon with the sun.
>    *‘the planets were aligned in syzygy’*

(Obviously the Moon will be at its "fullest" when it's exactly aligned, a precisely definable time.)

Comment: Get outa here. You need 'the exact moment of syzygy', which is far from a perfect match in any case.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the word you're looking for is the **zenith** or **apogee** of the full moon.

Comment: Maybe I'm being too concrete here, but neither zenith or apogee has any particular connection to the moment the moon is full.